# Spring-Boot HTTPS via windows-MY keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, keystore

I am trying to enable HTTPS for our spring-boot web service using the windows-MY keystore since some of our customers do not want to use a keystore located on the file-system.

I do know that it is possible to configure tomcat by itself to use the windows-MY keystore, however I am unable to find any information as to do this for spring-boot.

Is it possible to use the windows-MY keystore with spring-boot and if so, how do I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

In your application.yml file add the following section.  In the example below it is reading the certificate that visual studio generated previously and placed in the windows personal certificate store

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
      key-store: .
      key-store-type: windows-MY
      key-alias: ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate
```